# Double braces in angular not evaluating , going through as text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in angular.

```
<div vh-accordion-group id="{{$index}}" panel-class="panel-info">
    <div vh-accordion-header> </div>
    <div vh-accordion-body>   </div>
</div>
```

The HTML for the accordion-group is :

```
<div class="panel panel-info" ng-transclude>

</div>
```

Also, the js for the same is :

```
home.directive("vhAccordionGroup", ['version', function (version) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        panelClass: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: "JS/HomeModule/Directives/vhAccordion/vhAccordionGroup.html?v=" + version,
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.accordionId = $element.attr("id") + "vhAcc";

        this.getAccordionId = function () {
            return $scope.accordionId;
        };
    }],
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, vhAccordionGroupController) {
        element.addClass(scope.panelClass);
        scope.accordionId = element.attr("id") + "vhAcc";
    }
};
}]);
```

These accordions are called in a loop using ng-repeat.
The problem is the `{{$index}}` which I am passing in the Id is being taken as a string rather then an expression.
I need each of the accordions to have a unique Id so that they can open and close correctly.

Please let me know what I am missing, as I am a newbie to angular.

Comment: `$index` is a special variable that shows up inside and `ng-repeat`.  Are you repeating?

Comment: yes, but the value is not evaluated but taken as string

Comment: remove **double braces** then it will work for you.

Comment: What is the *actual* value that you are seeing?  Is the value the literal string `$index`?

Comment: @DavinTryon I am seeing the string but I need the value

Comment: What is the **value**?  Is it a `1` or is it `$index`?

Comment: I see, you are seeing `{{$index}}` correct?

Comment: @DavinTryon yes, but I need the value or any other value to distinguish the accordions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `id` to the isolated scope:

```
home.directive("vhAccordionGroup", ['version', function (version) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        panelClass: '@',
        id: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: "JS/HomeModule/Directives/vhAccordion/vhAccordionGroup.html?v=" + version,
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.accordionId = $scope.id + "vhAcc";

        this.getAccordionId = function () {
            return $scope.accordionId;
        };
    }],
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, vhAccordionGroupController) {
        element.addClass(scope.panelClass);
        scope.accordionId = scope.id + "vhAcc";
    }
};
}]);
```

Then, use `$scope.id` (and `scope.id`) instead of `$element.attr`.  `$element.attr` gives access to the actual DOM element and so it makes sense that the value would not be interpolated.